# How to set serial number in OAS (Oracle Analytics Publisher)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oas

My current result:

| No. | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | AB | col_amount |
| 2 |  |  | col_amount |
| 3 |  |  | col_amount |
| 4 | B | AS | col_amount |
| 5 |  |  | col_amount |
| 6 | T | TV | col_amount |

I want to get:

| No. | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | AB | col_amount |
|  |  |  | col_amount |
|  |  |  | col_amount |
| 2 | B | AS | col_amount |
|  |  |  | col_amount |
| 3 | T | TV | col_amount |

Comment: Your current result from what? Is this a question about modifying a query, or how the results are displayed by the client/application, or something else?

Comment: I want to set Serial number. Every method is ok by modify query or by format in tamplate.

Answer (score 0):

Following your previous question, you can use the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function in a `CASE` expression.

Given the sample data (slightly different than the question to show changes in `column_b` when `column_a` remains the same):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Column_A, Column_B, Column_C) AS
SELECT '01', 'AB', 'col_amount' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01', 'AB', 'col_amount' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01', 'AC', 'col_amount' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '02', 'OA', 'col_amount' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '03', 'OE', 'col_amount' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '03', 'OE', 'col_amount' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '04', 'OE', 'col_amount' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '04', 'XX', 'col_amount' FROM DUAL;
```

Then, if you want to number based on changes in `column_a` and `column_b` then:

```sql
SELECT CASE b_rn WHEN 1 THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY column_a, column_b) END
         AS no,
       CASE a_rn WHEN 1 THEN column_a END AS column_a,
       CASE b_rn WHEN 1 THEN column_b END AS column_b,
       column_c
FROM   (
  SELECT column_a,
         column_b,
         column_c,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_a ORDER BY column_b, column_c)
           AS a_rn,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_a, column_b ORDER BY column_c)
           AS b_rn
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which outputs:

| NO | COLUMN_A | COLUMN_B | COLUMN_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 | AB | col_amount |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | col_amount |
| 2 | *null* | AC | col_amount |
| 3 | 02 | OA | col_amount |
| 4 | 03 | OE | col_amount |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | col_amount |
| 5 | 04 | OE | col_amount |
| 6 | *null* | XX | col_amount |

Or, if you only want to number based on changes in `column_a` then you can use:

```sql
SELECT CASE a_rn WHEN 1 THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY column_a) END
         AS no,
       CASE a_rn WHEN 1 THEN column_a END AS column_a,
       CASE b_rn WHEN 1 THEN column_b END AS column_b,
       column_c
FROM   (
  SELECT column_a,
         column_b,
         column_c,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_a ORDER BY column_b, column_c)
           AS a_rn,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_a, column_b ORDER BY column_c)
           AS b_rn
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which outputs:

| NO | COLUMN_A | COLUMN_B | COLUMN_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 | AB | col_amount |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | col_amount |
| *null* | *null* | AC | col_amount |
| 2 | 02 | OA | col_amount |
| 3 | 03 | OE | col_amount |
| *null* | *null* | *null* | col_amount |
| 4 | 04 | OE | col_amount |
| *null* | *null* | XX | col_amount |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mushz27F)